# How do I linearly interpolate past missing values using future values in a while loop?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I am using MATLAB R2020a on a MacOS. I am trying to remove outlier values in a while loop. This involves calculating an exponentially weighted moving mean and then comparing this a vector value. If the conditions are met, the vector input is then added to a separate vector of 'acceptable' values. The while loop then advances to the next input and calculates the new exponentially weighted moving average which includes the newly accepted vector input.
However, if the condition is not met, I written code so that, instead of adding the input sample, a zero is added to the vector of 'acceptable' values. Upon the next acceptable value being added, I currently have it so the zero immediately before is replaced by the mean of the 2 framing acceptable values. However, this only accounts for one past zero and not for multiple outliers. Replacing with a framing mean may also introduce aliaising errors.

Is there any way that the zeros can instead be replaced by linearly interpolating the "candidate outlier" point using the gradient based on the framing 2 accepted vector input values? That is, is there a way of counting backwards within the while loop to search for and replace zeros as soon as a new 'acceptable' value is found?

I would very much appreciate any suggestions, thanks in advance.

```
%Calculate exponentially weighted moving mean and tau without outliers
accepted_means = zeros(length(cycle_periods_filtered),1); % array for accepted exponentially weighted means
    accepted_means(1) = cycle_periods_filtered(1);
    k = zeros(length(cycle_periods_filtered),1); % array for accepted raw cycle periods
    m = zeros(length(cycle_periods_filtered), 1); % array for raw periods for all cycles with outliers replaced by mean of framing values
    k(1) = cycle_periods_filtered(1); 
    m(1) = cycle_periods_filtered(1);
    tau = m/3; % pre-allocation for efficiency
    i = 2; % index for counting through input signal
    j = 2; % index for counting through accepted exponential mean values
    n = 2; % index for counting through raw periods of all cycles
    cycle_index3(1) = 1;
    while i <= length(cycle_periods_filtered)
        mavCurrent = (1 - 1/w(j))*accepted_means(j - 1) + (1/w(j))*cycle_periods_filtered(i);
          if cycle_periods_filtered(i) < 1.5*(accepted_means(j - 1)) && cycle_periods_filtered(i) > 0.5*(accepted_means(j - 1))  % Identify high and low outliers
            accepted_means(j) = mavCurrent;
            k(j) = cycle_periods_filtered(i);
            m(n) = cycle_periods_filtered(i);
            cycle_index3(n) = i;
            tau(n) = m(n)/3;
            
             
            if m(n - 1) == 0
                m(n - 1) = (k(j) + k(j - 1))/2;
                tau(n - 1) = m(n)/3;
            end
            
            j = j + 1;
            n = n + 1; 
            
            
          else
            m(n) = 0;
            n = n + 1;     
          end   
        i = i + 1;
    end
    % Scrap the tail
    accepted_means(j - 1:end)=[];
    k(j - 1:end) = [];
```

Comment: Why you don't just completely remove the values that you recognize as outliers? If I understand what you're trying to do, changing the "outlier" values to this interpolation would not change the moving average, and that should be exactly the same as removing them but with extra-steps.

Comment: Hi, the values cannot be completely removed since the 'tau' variable has to have the same number of values as the 'cycle_periods_filtered' variable for further analysis. The moving average is for identifying outlier raw period values and thus filtering the signal. These outliers in turn need to be replaced with raw period values that would fit the linear trend to then obtain 'tau' values from that. I realise now that I misworded my question; it should be "the framing 2 accepted input vector values" instead of "accepted moving averages"